# Get user defined type OID in Postgresql extension C

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm developing an extension to PostgreSQL using C. I created a user-defined type called geo_trajc_elem. I also created a function to generate an array of this new type.

```
  ArrayType *result_array;
  struct geo_trajc_elem *traje = (struct geo_trajc_elem *)palloc(sizeof(struct geo_trajc_elem));

  Timestamp time_el = PG_GETARG_TIMESTAMP(1);
  struct geo_point *pt = PG_GETARG_GEOPOINT_TYPE_P(2);

  int16 typlen;
  bool typbyval;
  char typalign;

  Datum datum_element;


  traje = DatumGetGeoTrajETypeP(DirectFunctionCall2(get_trajectory_elem, PointerGetDatum(time_el), PointerGetDatum(pt)));
  datum_element = PointerGetDatum(traje);

  /* Oid element_type = get_fn_expr_argtype(fcinfo->flinfo, 0); */ 

  Oid element_type = ?

  get_typlenbyvalalign(element_type, &typlen, &typbyval, &typalign);
```

Is there a function to get the oid -type of object? Like get_oid_elem (struct geo_trajc_elem)

In this case, it is not possible to use get_fn_expr_argtype because I am not passing the new type as argument but creating it in the function itself, correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ugh, you just reminded me of how horrid PostgreSQL's C-level array API is.

Comment: Give a little work......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the `Oid` that belongs to a certain type name, you have to consult `pg_type`.

You can use the function `typenameTypeId` from `parser/parse_type.h` with NULL as first argument for that purpose.

To get the `Oid` of the element type if you have the array type `Oid`, use `get_element_type` from `utils/lsyscache.h`.

Comment: You can't add preprocessor definitions for oids of user-defined types, as they can vary DB instance to DB instance.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you very much for your response, that's what I wanted... I just needed to create the type TypeName ;D